# xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("tiles").hasChildNodes is not a function?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Alright, so I'm getting this error `xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("tiles").hasChildNodes is not a function` from this code: `xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("tiles").hasChildNodes()`.

Now I've been using tutorials, and they're all saying this should work, so what am I doing wrong?

Edit:
xml file:

```
< ?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
<level>
    <tiles>
        <row>1000000000000001</row>
        <row>1000000000000001</row>
        <row>1000000000000001</row>
        <row>1000000000000001</row>
        <row>1000000000000001</row>
        <row>1000000000000001</row>
        <row>1000000000000001</row>
        <row>1111111111111111</row>
    </tiles>
</level>
```

Comment: Per the discussion in the answer below, people are clearly guessing at your setup. Please provide a full working example of your code, and the OS/browser/version you are having trouble with.

Answer (score 3):

`getElementsByTagName()` returns an array of elements with the passed tag name. If you were looking to test if the first/only `<tiles>` element has child nodes, try:

```
xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("tiles")[0].hasChildNodes()
```

If not, please specify what you're trying to do.

Comment: xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("tiles")[0] is undefined

Comment: Then perhaps `xmlDoc` does not contain any `<tiles>` element? You can test `xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("tiles")[0].length` first, to catch that case.

Comment: Alright, I'll try that. I edited in my xml file to the first post.

Comment: if xmlDoc.getElementByTagName("tiles")[0] is undefined, then xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("titles")[0].length is also undefined. The thing you should check is if xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("titles") has any elements, before you go to read one of them. Something like
xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("titles").count > 0

if you want to go through all the elements by the tag, you can probably have a for loop which breaks when the iterator reaches this count